# Powershell pipe concatenate value into curl url

Tags: powershell, curl

I am trying to concatenate the version value from my package.json and append it to a url and execute using curl.

I have this

```
Get-Content package.json | Out-String | ConvertFrom-Json | Select-Object -Expand version
```

But I want something like this-

```
 Get-Content package.json | Out-String | ConvertFrom-Json | Select-Object -Expand version | curl http://localhost:3000/api/version/update/<version variable here>
```

But I am unsure how to append the version variable output from Select-Object -Expand onto the url of the next curl command.

Is this possible in a single piped powershell command? Should I use InvokeWebRequest instead of curl?

Comment: `curl` is not compatible with PowerShell pipeline tho, you could for example create a wrapper function for it and that would work with pipeline.

Comment: `Get-Content package.json |ConvertFrom-Json |% { curl "http://.../$($_.version)"}`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Awesome thanks this was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Pipeline input is relayed to external programs as *stdin input*, whereas **what you're looking for is to make the pipeline input part of an *argument* to pass to the external `curl` program.**<sup>[1]</sup>

While using a [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) call, in whose [script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) (`{ ... }`) you can refer to the pipeline input object at hand via the [automatic `$_` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#_) so as to make it part of an argument, is definitely an option,<sup>[2]</sup> the simpler solution is to
**take advantage of PowerShell's ability to pass the output from arbitrary expressions or commands as command arguments**.

In the following command, `$(...)`, the [subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#subexpression-operator--), is used to embed your command's output in an [expandable string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings) (`"..."`):

```
curl "http://localhost:3000/api/version/update/$(
  (Get-Content -Raw package.json | ConvertFrom-Json).version
)"
```

<sup>Note: Even though the `$(...)` subexpression is spread across multiple lines *for readability*, its *output* is whatever the expression *evaluates to* - be it single-line (as in this case, presumably) or multi-line.</sup>

Note the use of `-Raw` with [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content), which causes the input file to be read *in full, as a single string*, which is by far the fastest way to read a text file in PowerShell.

- *Not* using `-Raw` and piping to [`Out-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-string) is an *inefficient* way to achieve the same effect, *except* that a trailing newline is needlessly appended (see [GitHub issue #14444](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14444)).
- Either way, [`ConvertFrom-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json) equally accepts *multiple* input strings, so even using `Get-Content` *alone* - without `-Raw` -  would work.
- `(...).version` is a more concise and efficient alternative to `Select-Object -ExpandProperty Version`, which, however, involves collecting the output from the command enclosed in `(...)` *in memory, up front* - which is definitely *not* a problem in this case.

---

[2] For the sake of completeness, here's the **pipeline-based alternative using `ForEach-Object`**, adapted from [Mathias R. Jessen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen)'s helpful comment:

```
Get-Content -Raw package.json |  
  ConvertFrom-Json |
    ForEach-Object { "http://localhost:3000/api/version/update/$($_.version)" }
```

---

<sup>[1] Assuming you're using *PowerShell (Core) 7+*. In *Windows PowerShell*, `curl` is a built-alias of the [`Invoke-WebRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest) cmdlet.</sup>